# PL/SQL Query not fetching limited records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, package

I have following query in a package

```
l_sql := 'SELECT  table_name.field1,
                  table_name.field2,
                  table_name.field3
            FROM table_name
            WHERE table_name.status = ''ACTIVE'' AND
                  table_name.replication_date >= SYSDATE - :l'

OPEN zequi_cur FOR l_sql USING l_days_between_start;
```

Ideally, it should select only those records which satisfy the condition `SYSTDATE-:l`. The value of `l` is `730492`. But its still fetching ALL the records. and this table has about 30 million records, which makes this query forever to return. any ideas, what could be possible reason that its not fetching only particular records?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SYSDATE-730492 gives a date in the year 10 AD i.e. 2000 years ago.  I can't imagine that is what you meant?

If your start date is in the year 0010 you will get 730492 as the difference:

```
SQL> select to_date ('22-NOV-2010 04.50.18 PM','DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SS AM')
  2         - to_date ('16-NOV-0010 04.59.22 PM','DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SS AM') as diff
  3  from dual;

      DIFF
----------
730492.994
```

Comment: the value of `l_days_between_start` is being calculated from this expression. `l_days_between_start := l_now - i_start_date;' the value of `l_now = 22-NOV-10 04.50.18 PM` and the value of `i_start_date = 16-NOV-10 04.59.22 PM`. which is giving `l_days_between_start = 730492.9937037037037037037037037037037037`. _whats wrong here_ ?? :(

Comment: I suspect that the century component of l_start_date (which you aren't displaying here) is 00 not 20.

Comment: Your expected answer is between 5 and 6. 730492 just doesn't pass the smell test!

Comment: isn't it same for `l_now` and `i_start_date`? how to fix it?

Comment: @Axn: yes, thats right. but the question is how to fix it now. I am going with default settings :s ..

Comment: I have updated my answer.  How to fix it?  How did you get the value into i_start_date in the first place?

Comment: Also, why not directly use the start date in the query? Why do the indirect SYSDATE - something?

Comment: It will be useful to show the data types of all the variables involved

Comment: okay. that makes sense now. the `i_start_date` is being fetched from a table. I inserted the value in the table as `UPDATE paramstable SET VALUE = '16-NOV-10 17:59:22'`. I thought, by default it will assum `10` as `2010`. What should be the fix?

Comment: UPDATE paramstable SET VALUE = to_date('16-NOV-10 17:59:22', 'DD-MON-RR hh24:mi:ss')

Comment: `i_start_date, l_now` are `DATE` - `l_days_between_start` is `NUMBER`

Comment: Is the `VALUE` column in the `paramstable` a varchar type?

Comment: Axn suggested a fix already: UPDATE paramstable SET VALUE = to_date('16-NOV-10 17:59:22', 'DD-MON-RR hh24:mi:ss')

Comment: I will have to partially retract my suggestion. It is better to do the to_date while retrieving the value than while putting it in the table.

Comment: thats how its being fetched from the table in the code `SELECT TO_DATE(value, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - (i_offset/24) FROM   paramstable WHERE  name = 'last_date';`

the value is fetched into `l_rep_date`  which is `DATE` type variable. (the value of the `i_offset` is `0` for current testing)

Comment: @alee Note the format string that I'm using. 'RR' for the year part is a must if you're using only 2 digit years.

Comment: I just updated the table using `RR` format and I got 3 (aprox) days in `l_days_between_start`. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

To expand slightly on @Tony's post, when you subtract a number from a DATE value the unit-of-measure of that number is assumed to be days.  Therefore, subtracting 730492 days is equivalent to subtracting about 2000 years.  I suspect that's not what you wanted to do.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Besides fixing your date range, is there any particular reason to use dynamic SQL? Maybe it's better to use a static cursor:

```
declare
  cursor c_cur(b_offset in number) is
    SELECT  table_name.field1,
            table_name.field2,
            table_name.field3
      FROM  table_name
      WHERE table_name.status = ''ACTIVE'' AND
            table_name.replication_date >= SYSDATE - b_offset
  ;
begin
  open c_cur(l_days_between_start);
  ...
end;
```